# create a blockchain graph in ggplot or any other plotting package

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following `data.frame`:

```
POP1    POP2    FST
ES13-15 ES16-18   0.0109
ES19-21 SA7-9     0.0587
SA7-9   SA13-15   0.0287
ES10-12 ES37-38   0.0816
ES34-36 ES37-38   0.0205
ES28-30 ES37-38   0.0425
ES22-24 ES25-27   0.0108
ES19-21 SA22-25   0.0940
ES6-8   ES13-15   0.0081
ES1-3   ES7-9     0.0418
ES7-9   ES16-18   0.0224
ES19-21 ES37-38   0.0894
ES1-3   ES34-36   0.0874
ES19-21 ES25-27   0.0320
ES19-21 SA19-21   0.1184
SA7-9   SA16-18   0.0361
ES13-15 SA19-21   0.0852
ES22-24 SA7-9     0.0193
ES28-30 SA7-9     0.0335
ES4-6   ES34-36   0.0794
```

Here is `dput` of it :

```
structure(list(POP1 = c("ES1-3", "SA4-6", "ES31-33", "ES1-3", 
"ES34-36", "SA1-3", "ES6-8", "ES7-9", "ES25-27", "ES7-9", "SA10-12", 
"ES1-3", "ES10-12", "ES10-12", "ES22-24", "ES10-12", "ES37-38", 
"ES34-36", "ES4-6", "ES16-18"), POP2 = c("ES10-12", "SA16-18", 
"ES37-38", "SA13-15", "ES37-38", "SA16-18", "ES34-36", "ES10-12", 
"SA1-3", "SA22-25", "SA16-18", "ES6-8", "SA13-15", "SA22-25", 
"SA13-15", "ES31-33", "SA10-12", "SA4-6", "ES22-24", "SA13-15"
), FST = c(0.0123, 0.0531, 0.039, 0.0744, 0.0205, 0.0831, 0.0678, 
0.0257, 0.045, 0.0635, 0.0138, 0.0193, 0.0782, 0.0726, 0.0522, 
0.0612, 0.0719, 0.0624, 0.0255, 0.0819)), row.names = c(4L, 214L, 
178L, 18L, 187L, 208L, 51L, 61L, 158L, 78L, 223L, 2L, 92L, 95L, 
150L, 85L, 199L, 189L, 28L, 123L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to produce a graph that takes the columns POP1 and POP2 and produce a blockchain graph like this one:

[image]

Where each block represents the pairwise relationship of my `data.frame` in a rowwise manner. For example the first row ES13-15 would be a block in the picture linked with ES16-18. The value of FST would be great if could stand on top of the line that links the blocks. In the former case, the values 0.0109 would be above the line that links the aforementioned blocks.

Some code to fork the blocks would also be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you running into problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the 'igraph' package for this:

```
Using your `dput()` output, which is different from data.frame you have shared.

library(igraph)
df = structure(list(POP1 = c("ES1-3", "SA4-6", "ES31-33", "ES1-3", 
"ES34-36", "SA1-3", "ES6-8", "ES7-9", "ES25-27", "ES7-9", "SA10-12", 
"ES1-3", "ES10-12", "ES10-12", "ES22-24", "ES10-12", "ES37-38", 
"ES34-36", "ES4-6", "ES16-18"), POP2 = c("ES10-12", "SA16-18", 
"ES37-38", "SA13-15", "ES37-38", "SA16-18", "ES34-36", "ES10-12", 
"SA1-3", "SA22-25", "SA16-18", "ES6-8", "SA13-15", "SA22-25", 
"SA13-15", "ES31-33", "SA10-12", "SA4-6", "ES22-24", "SA13-15"
), FST = c(0.0123, 0.0531, 0.039, 0.0744, 0.0205, 0.0831, 0.0678, 
0.0257, 0.045, 0.0635, 0.0138, 0.0193, 0.0782, 0.0726, 0.0522, 
0.0612, 0.0719, 0.0624, 0.0255, 0.0819)), row.names = c(4L, 214L, 
178L, 18L, 187L, 208L, 51L, 61L, 158L, 78L, 223L, 2L, 92L, 95L, 
150L, 85L, 199L, 189L, 28L, 123L), class = "data.frame")

g<-graph_from_data_frame(d = df[,c(1,2)],directed = TRUE)
plot(g,edge.arrow.size=0.1,vertex.shape="rectangle")
```

[image: Blockchain Graph]

Comment: oh yes sorry I selected random rows as an example of the whole dataframe and did not set a seed.

Comment: Yes there is. Try this: `E(g)$weight = df$FST` and then: `plot(g, edge.label = E(g)$weight,edge.arrow.size=0.1,vertex.shape="rectangle")`